# Updating the "Hero Image" in a TVOS template

Tags: javascript, tvos, tvml, tvjs

I'm trying to dynamically update the hero image source, inside a TVOS `productTemplate`.

I'm able to do this for the description, for example:

```
function changeDescription(incomingString) {
    if (incomingString) {
        var theDescription = myDoc.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0);
        theDescription.innerHTML = incomingString;
    }
}
```

.. but it's not working for the src value for the hero image:

```
function changeHeroImage(incomingString) {
    console.log("local path: " + incomingString)
    if (incomingString) {
        var theHero = myDoc.getElementsByTagName("heroImg").item(0);
        var theHeroSrc = theHero.getAttribute("src");
        theHeroSrc.value = incomingString;
        // theHeroSrc.innerHTML = incomingString;
    }
}
```

I've verified the path is correct; what else should I look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```
theHero.setAttribute('src', incomingString)
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you. Interestingly, updating the hero image does not update the background - but that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

Updating images should use the `src` attribute, not `value`:

```
function changeHeroImage(incomingString) {
    console.log("local path: " + incomingString)
    if (incomingString) {
        var theHero = myDoc.getElementsByTagName("heroImg").item(0);
        theHero.src = incomingString;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, yet the icon is still not changing (in my simulator, at least). I've checked that the incoming string is correct, and `theHero` appears to be a correct IKDOMElement.

Comment: Confirmed, doesn't work on a real AppleTV either. Might TVJS have a different syntax for this?